# HTML5 video tag doesn't work in mobile devices

Tags: html

I am using a input tag and type="file" attribute to get he video file and using java script invoking a function that plays a video. I works on my PC with chrome but doesn't play on mobile devices (android phones and ipad). Below is my code. I am stuck with this and greatly appreciate any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Welcome</h1>
<h2> Step1.record a video</h2>
    <form action="{{ upload_url }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       Click this button to start recording, Don't worry you can preview befor uploadiong the video:
        <input id="uploadImage" type="file"   name="video" accept="video/*" onchange="PreviewImage();" capture ><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <video id="uploadPreview" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;" controls/>
        <!--<source src="" type="video/mp4">-->
        <!--<source src="" type="video/ogg">-->
        <!--<source src="" type="video/webm">-->
    </video>
</body>
<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PreviewImage() {
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            var video = document.getElementById("uploadPreview");
            video.src = oFREvent.target.result;
            video.play();
        };
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `FileReader` has very limited browser support and it is associated with few bugs, I have tried your code in **Android chrome 45** but its not working there as well.
>
> Refer http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader to know supported browsers for `FileReader`. Also go through the *Known Issues* section at the bottom which says that it has *bugs* in `iOS` and `webkit`

**As `FileReader` is not a stable solution, I would suggest you to go `server side` for such utilities**